# Unexpected error resloved by using <iostream> header

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor

*Sorry if this code is too long. When I tried to reproduce this problem, it show the expect result.*

So I was trying to make a BigInteger header:

BIGINT.h

```cpp
#ifndef BIGINT_H
#define BIGINT_H

//#include <iostream> 

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

extern short DEFAULT_BASE;

class BigInt
{
private:
    bool m_sign; // (0/false) mean negative, (1/true) mean positive
    std::string m_number;
    unsigned char m_base;

public:
    // constructor
    BigInt(std::string number = "0", unsigned char base = DEFAULT_BASE);
    BigInt(unsigned char base, std::string number = "0");
    BigInt(const BigInt &copy);

    //destructor
    ~BigInt();

    // get member value
    std::string number() const;
    unsigned char base() const;
    bool is_number_positive() const;

    // I/O overload
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const BigInt& bigInt);
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, BigInt& bigInt);


};


#endif // BIGINT_H
```

BIGINT.cpp

```cpp
#include "BIGINT.h"

short DEFAULT_BASE = 10;

// constructor
BigInt::BigInt(std::string number, unsigned char base)
{
{
    {
        int i{0};
        int numberOfSubtraction{0};
        while (number[i] == '-' || number[i] == '+')
        {
            numberOfSubtraction += number[i] == '-';
            ++i;
        }

        m_sign = numberOfSubtraction % 2 == 0;

        number = number.substr(i);
    }
    // std::cerr << base << ' ';
    assert(base >= 2 && base <= 36);
    for(char &i : number)
    {
        if(isdigit(i)) assert(i - '0' < base);
        else if(isalpha(i)) assert(i - 'A' + 10 < base);
        m_number += toupper(i);
    }
    m_base = base;


}

BigInt::BigInt(unsigned char base, std::string number)
{
    {
        int i{0};
        int numberOfSubtraction{0};
        while (number[i] == '-' || number[i] == '+')
        {
            numberOfSubtraction += number[i] == '-';
            ++i;
        }

        m_sign = numberOfSubtraction % 2 == 0;

        number = number.substr(i);
    }
    // std::cerr << base << ' ';
    assert(base >= 2 && base <= 36);
    for(char &i : number)
    {
        if(isdigit(i)) assert(i - '0' < base);
        else if(isalpha(i)) assert(i - 'A' + 10 < base);
        m_number += toupper(i);
    }
    m_base = base;

}

BigInt::BigInt(const BigInt &copy)
{
    m_number = copy.m_number;
    m_base = copy.m_base;
}

// destructor
BigInt::~BigInt() = default;

// get member value
std::string BigInt::number() const {return m_number;}
unsigned char BigInt::base() const {return m_base;}
bool BigInt::is_number_positive() const {return m_sign;}

// I/O overload
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const BigInt& bigInt)
{
    if(!bigInt.m_sign) out << '-';
    out << bigInt.m_number;

    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, BigInt& bigInt)
{
    std::string number;
    in >> number;
    {
        int i{0};
        int numberOfSubtraction{0};
        while (number[i] == '-' || number[i] == '+')
        {
            numberOfSubtraction += number[i] == '-';
            ++i;
        }

        bigInt.m_sign = numberOfSubtraction % 2 == 0;

        number = number.substr(i);
    }
    for(char &i : number)
    {
        if(isdigit(i)) assert(i - '0' < DEFAULT_BASE);
        else if(isalpha(i)) assert(i - 'A' + 10 < DEFAULT_BASE);
        bigInt.m_number += toupper(i);
    }
    return in;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "BIGINT.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    BigInt bigInt{"+-+---+-+--+1", 10};
    std::cout << bigInt ;
}
```

So I run this, and it assert:
`Assertion failed: base >= 2 && base <= 36, file D:\phamngocphuc\C++ project\BigInt\BIGINT.cpp, line 49`, which is unexpected because:

Firstly, it should call this constructor `BigInt(std::string number = "0", unsigned char base = DEFAULT_BASE);`

and not this `BigInt(unsigned char base, std::string number = "0");`

And my base actually should be good: `(10 >= 2 && 10 <= 36)` is `true`

Second, when I `#include <iostream>` in BIGINT.h to debug, and run it, it actually show `-1` which is expected result.

So why is this happening?

Comment: How are you compiling that code? Because it *shouldn’t even compile* without the `iostream` header.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I did ```include <iostream>``` in main, but not in BIGINT.h. Please show me why that wouldn't compile

Comment: `m_base = base;` is done **after** you do `assert(i - '0' < m_base)`, so you have UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh stupid me. But it *still* throw that ```assert```

Comment: @Jarod42 I should also point out that it throw this ```assert(base >= 2 && base <= 36);
```

Comment: @justANewbie But it needs to be included in `BiGINT.cpp`! Again, please show how you’re compiling the code.

Comment: *"it should call this constructor [..] and not this [..]"*, you show twice the same constructor..

Comment: I make this by Code::Blocks project, so the compiler should both compile both files?

Comment: You *need* `<iostrem>` if you want to use `std::ostream` and `std::istream`.

Comment: What happens if you place the `#include <iostream>` directive in `BIGINT.cpp` rather than `BIGINT.hpp`?  Does that give the expected result?  `BIGINT.cpp` is where the `std::ostream` etc. are actually used and hence it probably relies on certain initialization that is typically performed by nifty counters defined in the associated header.  Bit of a guess though.

Comment: @G.M. Yes it give the expected result. But I'm wondering why my compiler manages to compile this without ```iostream``` and give that assert

Comment: @KonradRudolph I run this in Debug mode, didn't turn any optimization on, and Code::Blocks manages to compile that code without any warning, and now it throws this obscure bug? Wow.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Unrelated to Code::Blocks, it is just that standard include does some other include/forward declaration which unfortunately are exported too :/ module should solve that.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah right, I had overlooked the other includes in the header file. OK, so C::B is probably not the culprit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mark the offending constructor as deleted [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc0df42c697ab59b).

Compiler spots where it is used, (and it is not where you think):

Issue is there:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const BigInt& bigInt)
{
    if(!bigInt.m_sign) out << '-';
    out << bigInt.m_number;

    return out;
}
```

Without the include `<iostream>` (it seems you have some forward declaration from other std include to be able to use those types), `out << '-';` just found as candidate `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const BigInt& bigInt)` (recursive call would also be problematic though).

So construct a `BigInt` from `'-'` (`BigInt(unsigned char base, std::string number = "0");`).

And then your error.

Comment: Thank you so much! Btw, why does that assertion fail?

Comment: because `'-'` is not a valid base.